# Different results are obtained while rounding decimals

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
double radius = 5;
double area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);            
// System.out.println(area);

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(area).setScale(2, HALF_UP);
// BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(area).setScale(2, ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(bd.toString());
```

The above output gets printed as 78.54, but if I perform the same operation via the calculator (windows calc interface) the output comes out as 78.57 (i.e. `22/7 * 25`).

Why is there an inconsistency

Comment: This just in: pi isn't actually 22/7.

Comment: If I do PI*25 in calc.exe I get 78.539..., i.e. rounded it's 78.54

Comment: When I was in primary school, our teacher taught us that the definition of PI was 22/7. Sadly, I believed this until I was 14 years old. Biggest trauma from my childhood.

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: Me too! Those were the times :(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you using `22/7` as an approximate value for PI? Because `22/7` is `3.142857142857...` where PI is approximately `3.14159...`. This explains your rounding inconsistencies.

The approximation of PI that is used in the JVM is documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Math.PI). According to the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI), it is:

> The *double* value that is closer than any other to *pi*

Comment: so what exactly is PI, should I just assume that Math.PI gives me the right value and not 22/7

Comment: Yes. Its value is `3.141592653589793` [truncated] ,You can try `3.141592653589793 * 25` in `calc`

Comment: @Joe since PI is a constant I assume it's just stored up to some precision setting. There's no need to calculate a constant that can't change (ald calculating it would have a performance hit too, although normally not measurable).

Comment: Pi is 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi

Comment: Yes, you can assume that ``Math.PI`` is MUCH more closer to the actual PI than 22/7. You can see its exact value in the Java documentation http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Math.PI

Comment: Official methematical background on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80 - but it's still an approximation and `22/7 != Math.PI` is always true (in mathematics).

Comment: Can you point out in your answer clearly that Pi is also not `3.14159`, rather that this is a slightly more accurate approximation. As it stands I hesitate to upvote it.

Comment: @wds: You're right, it wasn't very clever of me to answer a question based on a bad approximation of PI with another approximation of PI.

Answer (score 6):

`22/7` is approximation to `PI` , Its not exact and so the result

Comment: You could use 3 as well; it's not that bad of an approximation and easier to calculate with

Comment: Did you hit submit prematurely?

Answer (score 1):

Almost completely off-topic (and its javascript). But its still a fun answer for actually visibly seeing PI being calculated.

This method is obviously super-super-slow at calculating PI...but is kinda fun to watch.

```
(function (t) {
    (function () {
        var a = 0,
            b = 1,
            d = 4,
            c = ~1e9;
        (function p() {
            if (!t) {
                return;
            }
            b -= 2;
            a -= d / b;
            d = -d;
            if (++c % 2000 === 0) {
                t.innerHTML = a;
                setTimeout(p, 13);
            } else {
                if (c) {
                    p();
                } else {
                    t.innerHTML = a;
                }
            }
        }());
    }());
}(document.getElementById("someplace-to-hold-the-calculation")))
```

---

[Philippe Leybaert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113570/philippe-leybaert) set up a [JSBin for it](http://jsbin.com/awupo4).

Comment: I actually use this function in loading messages sometimes. Like this: `Calculating PI to infinity, please wait...<span id='pi-calc'>3.14</span>`. I also use "Reticulating Splines", "It's still faster than you could draw it", and "Please wait. (As if you had any other choice.)". :-D